# Capitalizing first letter in android soft keyboard for edittext

Tags: android

I have edit text which accept string. I want that the first letter of the string  is capital for that I want to show keyboard with capital letter which default behavior of android.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

XML answer:

```
 android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

If you need to use more than one input type follow this:

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textPersonName"
```

! Do not use below code because it is deprecated:

```
android:capitalize="sentences" <!-- deprecated -->
```

Comment: i tried this but it is not working in my case m getting the keypad with the lower case letter

Answer (score 2):

You can also  make this using capitalize attribute...

```
 android:capitalize="sentences"
```

Comment: It's now deprecated and it's not working properly anymore. You should use the accepted answer instead.

Comment: This answer deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

you can also make this using **capitalize** attribute...

```
 <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:capitalize="characters" />
```

Comment: This answer deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

A more better way of achieving this desired output would be getting text from the editText and then capitalizing the first letter . This can be done using below one liner and would work for everyone , not like above XML attributes which doesn't seem to work in some cases.

```
String ACaps=yourText.toUpperCase().charAt(0)+searchText.substring(1,searchText.length());
```

where yourText is text from editText.

Answer (score -1):

Use in your xml:

```
android:capitalize="sentences"
```

Comment: This answer deprecated.